# FactoryGirl3, can't access factories anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory-bot, rspec-rails

After I upgraded to the new FactoryGirl, I updated the syntax of the factories I inherited.  Now, I bounce between either my factory isn't defined, or it's double defined.  All of the answers I have found online are using older versions/syntax, and none of the proposed solutions really allows me to call my factories.  I apologize for the file lengths, and I really appreciate your time!  This is what I have now after having wrestled with it for a while:

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  # config.mock_with :rspec
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  def test_sign_in(user)
    sign_in (user)
  end


  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

# Sequences    
  sequence :test_name do |n|
    "Test Name #{n}"
  end

  sequence :email do |n|
    "devnull#{n}@topsailtech.com"
  end

  sequence :block_offset do |n|
    n*100
  end

  sequence :venue_position do |n|
    n
  end

  sequence :sponsorship_position do |n|
    n
  end

  sequence :sponsor_position do |n|
    n
  end

  sequence :id do |n|
    n
  end

  # factories
  factory :account, :class => Account do 
    id { FactoryGirl.generate(:id) }
  end

  factory :invalid_account, :class => Account do 
    id ''
  end

  factory :activity, :class => Activity do 
    event { Conference.find_by_name('TechConf') }
    location { |a| a.event.areas.first }
    start_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
    end_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
    title { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
  end

  factory :invalid_activity, :class => Activity do 
    title ''
    start_time ''
    event ''
  end

  factory :administrator, :class => Administrator do |f|
    f.email { FactoryGirl.generate(:email) }
    f.first_name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.last_name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.password 'aBc123xYz!'
    f.password_confirmation 'aBc123xYz!'
  end

  factory :invalid_administrator, :class => Administrator do |f|
    f.email ''
    f.first_name ''
    f.last_name ''
    f.password 'x'
    f.password_confirmation 'y'
  end

  factory :area, :class => Area do |f|
    f.event_id { Festival.find_by_name('MusicFest').id }
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
  end

  factory :invalid_area, :class => Area do |f|
    f.name ''
    f.event ''
  end

  factory :artist, :class => Artist do |f|
    f.event_id { Festival.find_by_name('MusicFest').id }
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.bio 'This artist is really creative.'
    f.website 'www.topsailtech.com'
  end

  factory :invalid_artist, :class => Artist do |f|
    f.name ''
  end

  factory :booth, :class => Booth do |f|
    f.event_id { Festival.find_by_name('MusicFest').id }
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
  end

  factory :invalid_booth, :class => Booth do |f|
    f.name ''
  end

  factory :category, :class => Category do |f|
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.event { Festival.find_by_name('MusicFest') }
    f.parent { |attrs| attrs.event.categories.first }
    f.key { |a| a.name.parameterize('') }
  end

  factory :invalid_category, :class => Category do |f|
    f.name ''
    f.event ''
  end

  factory :top_level_category, :class => Category do |f|
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.event { Festival.find_by_name('MusicFest') }
    f.key { |a| a.name.parameterize('') }
  end

  factory :conference_session_speaker, :class => ConferenceSessionSpeaker do |f|
    f.conference_session { ConferenceSession.find_by_title('Giggler') }
    f.speaker { |a| a.conference_session.event.speakers.first }
  end

  factory :invalid_conference_session_speaker, :class => ConferenceSessionSpeaker do |f|
  end

  factory :conference_session_without_speaker, :class => ConferenceSession do |f|
    f.event { Conference.find_by_name('TechConf') }
    f.location { |a| a.event.venues.first }
    f.block_date  { |a| a.event.start_date }
    f.start_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
    f.end_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
    f.title 'Test Title'
    f.subtitle 'Test Sub-title'
    f.abstract 'Test abstract blah blah blah'
    f.track { |a| a.event.tracks.first }
  end

  factory :conference_session, :class => ConferenceSession, :parent => :conference_session_without_speaker do |f|
    f.speaker { |a| a.event.speakers.first }
  end

  factory :invalid_conference_session, :class => ConferenceSession do |f|
    f.event nil
    f.title ''
  end

  factory :conference, :class => Conference do |f|
    f.account_id { Factory.create(:account).id }
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.start_date { Date.today + 1 }
    f.end_date { Date.today + 3 }
    f.copyright 'Giggler, Inc.'
  end

  factory :invalid_conference, :class => Conference do |f|
    f.name ''
  end

  factory :festival, :class => Festival do |f|
    f.account_id { Factory.create(:account).id }
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.start_date { Date.today + 1 }
    f.end_date { Date.today + 3 }
    f.copyright 'Giggler, Inc.'
  end

  factory :invalid_festival, :class => Festival do |f|
    f.name ''
  end

  factory :performance, :class => Performance do |f|
    f.event { Festival.find_by_name('MusicFest') }
    f.location { |a| a.event.venues.first }
    f.contributor { |a| a.event.artists.first }
    f.block_date  { |a| a.event.start_date }
    f.start_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
    f.end_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
  end

  factory :invalid_performance, :class => Performance do |f|
  end

  factory :series, :class => Series do |f|
    f.event { Conference.find_by_name('TechConf') }
    f.location { |a| a.event.venues.first }
    f.block_date  { |a| a.event.start_date }
    f.start_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
    f.end_time  { FactoryGirl.generate(:block_offset) }
    f.title 'Test Title'
    f.subtitle 'Test Sub-title'
    f.abstract 'Test abstract blah blah blah'
    f.track { |a| a.event.tracks.first }
  end

  factory :invalid_series, :class => Series do |f|
    f.title ''
  end

  factory :speaker, :class => Speaker do |f|
    f.event { Conference.find_by_name('TechConf') }
    f.first_name 'John'
    f.last_name 'Doe'
    f.credentials 'Dr.'
    f.organization 'TechCom'
    f.title 'Director'
    f.website 'blahblahblahblahblah.com'
    f.street_address '123 Foo Road'
    f.city 'Townsville'
    f.state 'NC'
    f.zip_code '27519'
    f.bio 'Blah blah blah blah blah'
  end

  factory :invalid_speaker, :class => Speaker do |f|
  end

  factory :sponsor, :class => Sponsor do |f|
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.show_logo true
    f.website 'topsailtech.com'
    f.sponsorship { Factory.create(:sponsorship) }
  end

  factory :invalid_sponsor, :class => Sponsor do |f|
    f.name ''
  end

  factory :sponsorship, :class => Sponsorship do |f|
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    f.position { FactoryGirl.generate(:sponsorship_position) }
    f.show_logo true
    f.event { Conference.find_by_name('TechConf') }
  end

  factory :invalid_sponsorship, :class => Sponsorship do |f|
    f.name ''
    f.position ''
    f.show_logo ''
    f.event ''
  end

  factory :track, :class => Track do |f|
    f.event { Conference.find_by_name('TechConf') }
    f.name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
  end

  factory :invalid_track, :class => Track do |f|
    f.event ''
    f.name ''
  end

  factory :vendor, :class => Vendor do 
    association event :factory => :festival, :name => 'MusicFest'
    category { |a| a.event.categories.first }
    location { |a| a.event.venues.first }
    name { FactoryGirl.generate(:test_name) }
    bio 'They sell things.'
    website 'www.topsailtech.com'
  end

  factory :invalid_vendor, :class => Vendor do |f|
    f.name ''
  end

  factory :venue, :class => Venue do 
    event { Festival.find_by_name('MusicFest') }
    name test_name
    street_address '406 Blackwell St.'
    city 'Durham'
    state 'NC'
    zip_code '27701'
    position venue_position
    key { |a| a.name.parameterize('') }
  end

  factory :invalid_venue, :class => Venue do |f|
    f.name ''
  end
end
```

**controller/this_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GigViewController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  fixtures :all

  render_views

  describe "GET all GigViews" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = user_profile(:doc)
      @event = event(:merlefest)        
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      test_sign_in @user
      get :show, :id => @event.id
      response.should be_success
    end

    **... removed multiple other tests that work but don't use fixtures ...**

    it "should get music" do
      sign_in @user 
      venue = FactoryGirl.create(:venue)
      get :music, :id => @event.id
      response.should be_success
    end

  end
end
```

**Gemfile.lock (excerpt)**

```
factory_girl (3.0.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
factory_girl_rails (3.0.0)
  factory_girl (~> 3.0.0)
  railties (>= 3.0.0)
rails (3.1.3)
  actionmailer (= 3.1.3)
  actionpack (= 3.1.3)
  activerecord (= 3.1.3)
  activeresource (= 3.1.3)
  activesupport (= 3.1.3)
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  railties (= 3.1.3)
rspec-rails (2.9.0)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec (~> 2.9.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started over, and this is what I've got so far.  It works now, and I hope that posting this will help someone trying to get things started, as I was:

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Use color in STDOUT
  config.color_enabled = true

  # Use color not only in STDOUT but also in pagers and files
  config.tty = true

  # Use the specified formatter
  config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate  
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user_profile, :class => UserProfile do
    first_name 'John'
    last_name 'Doe'
    email { "#{first_name}.#{last_name}@example.com".downcase } 
    username 'johndoe'
    password 'johndoe'
    password_confirmation 'johndoe'
    association :account, :factory => :account 
  end

  factory :account, :class => Account do
   # id { FactoryGirl.generate(:id) }
  end

  factory :event, :class => Event do
    name 'Shakori'
    association :account, :factory => :account    
  end 
end
```

**controllers/account_controller.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AccountController do
  render_views

  describe "do not GET 'event" do

    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user_profile]
    end

    it "should fail when user is not logged in" do
      get :events
      response.should_not be_success
    end

  end

  describe "GET 'event'" do

    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user_profile]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user_profile, :username => 'johndoe' )
    end

    it "should be successful, if logged in" do
      get :events 
      response.should be_success
    end

  end


end
```